# Discord bot started returning unicode error messages in the middle of its runtime

Tags: python, unicode, discord, undefined

My discord bot ran completely fine, but in the middle of its runtime, without restarting, or me changing any of its files. We used its commands less than a minute before it stopped working, but then all of a sudden, it stopped responding to any command we threw at it. When i stopped the python process in the task manager and ran the bot from Atom, it gave me this error message whenever we sent any message: `return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 79: character maps to <undefined>`

I cannot make sense of this error message at all, what does it mean? Is there a way to fix it? And why did it all of a sudden begin to appear in the middle of its runtime?

some additional information: the line the the error occurs on is: `if open("totpal_guilds/" + message.guild.name + ".pkl", "r").read() == open("totpal_guilds/kort_dummy.pkl", "r").read():`
actually, it might be helpful to send the whole entire error message it threw at me:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\capta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\capta\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\discord bots\Kort async\kort_as.pyw", line 117, in on_message
    if open("totpal_guilds/" + message.guild.name + ".pkl", "r").read() == open("totpal_guilds/kort_dummy.pkl", "r").read():
  File "C:\Users\capta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 79: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: If those `.pkl` files are Python pickle files, they should be opened in binary mode - `"rb"`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks, i've noticed that mistake right after i posted the question... though i'm curious why it stopped working all of a sudden, when the code didn't change and it coped with only having "r" before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now noticed the mistake I have in my code, I didn't notice I had "r" instead of "rb" in the call for the open function. However, as far as I know, there isn't a way to mark a question as resolved without choosing a best answer, so i'm answering it myself so that the question doesn't bother anybody anymore.